# Current state of AI development

Tags: artificial-intelligence

Could someone please tell what is current state of practical human-like AI development in the world? Which projects reached most success and/or more promising? I only interested in developments which are going to match & exceed human capabilities in terms of thinking and reasoning.

I am not interested in practical narrow cases like translation, speech synthesis & recognition, OCR, robotics.

Pure intelligence is what I am looking for.

Comment: You call machine translation and speech "narrow"? This question should at least be community wiki, btw.

Comment: I agree that it should be comm. wiki, but I don't see how to do it :-)

Comment: Yes, machine translation and speech currently use algos which will never lead to thinking computer :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Could someone please tell what is
>   current state of practical human-like
>   AI development in the world?

[OpenCog](http://opencog.org/) immediately comes to mind.

> In order to put this architecture to
>   work, we have crafted a roadmap based
>   on roughly mimicking the environment
>   and development of young human
>   children. A series of child-level
>   learning tasks has been carefully laid
>   out, which may be manifested via
>   either virtual world agents or
>   physical robots, and which lead from
>   infant-level capabilities up to the
>   grade school level. These tasks cover
>   all the major cognitive capabilities
>   displayed by young humans, and involve
>   the integration of all major aspects
>   of human intelligence, including
>   perception, action, cognition,
>   learning, memory, creativity,
>   socialization, language,
>   self-modeling, etc.

**Edit:** Not sure how you are misled and think it is about "pop robotics", this page might summarize the project better for a new comer: [The Open Cognition Project](http://wiki.opencog.org/w/The_Open_Cognition_Project)

Comment: Looks nice, but I am interested in pure intelligence, this looks more like pop robotics :-)

Comment: it is not. read through, here is a quote "We're undertaking a serious effort aimed at building a thinking machine."

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

### [ASIMO is learning](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P9ByGQGiVMg)

Honda's ASIMO learns to identify objects.

---

### [Robot's Body of Knowledge](http://spectrum.ieee.org/robotics/artificial-intelligence/a-robots-body-of-knowledge)

A team of European researchers built a robot that tries to learn not just from preprogrammed instructions or massive processing power but from reaching out and touching things. The PACO-Plus project represents a new breed of robots that don't try to anticipate every possible environmental input, instead seeking out stimuli using their bodies to create a joint mental and physical map of the possibilities. Using this approach, the robot has learned to recognize objects like a box of cereals amid other boxes in a kitchen—now can it fix breakfast?

Comment: Robotics is also not what I am lookin. Pure intelligence wanted :-)

Comment: Are you sure there is such a thing?